# Does optimizing a bijection-transformed value affect performance or accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, tensorflow-probability, gpflow

If I want to optimize a function with respect to some constrained value, I can find a bijective map between an unconstrained space and the constrained space, then optimize the composition of the original function and the bijective map with respect to the unconstrained value.

Does optimizing in a different space affect the performance or accuracy of optimization? And does it vary between bijective maps?

My use case is training constrained Gaussian process model hyperparameters in GPflow using TensorFlow Probability's bijectors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you might have for example some variable that is constrained to be positive and want to optimize it. And for that you train the variable in the unconstrained space?

That would be pretty common in machine learning where you for example enforce a variance (of let's say the likelihood) to be positive by taking the exponent of the unconstrained value.

I guess the effect on the optimization very much depends on how you optimize it. For gradient based methods it does have an effect, and sometimes small tricks are helpful to improve those issues (e.g. shifting, so that your transformation is tf.exp(shift_val + unconstrained_variable) ).

And yes afaik it varies inbetween different mappings. In my example, the softplus and exponential transformation result in different gradients. Tough I'm not sure if there's a consent on which one is preferable.

I'd just try a few different ones. As long as it doesn't lead to numerical issues, either transformation/bijection should be fine.

EDIT: just to clarify. The bijection should not affect the solution space, just the optimization path itself.

Comment: Agree. Note that `tfp.util.TransformedVariable(1., tfb.Exp())` can be useful for practically implementing this. If you have a `tf.Module` subclass and assign `self.foo = TransformedVariable(..)`, you can later use `module.trainable_variables` to get the set of variables for optimization.